# Can we cover these topological by compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose M is a topological space which is Hausdorff and second countable. Can we say that M can be written as countable union of compact sets?

Since M is second countable it has a countable basis.Then how can we find those compact sets or how can we find the counter example?

Comment: Why forth that contorted and inappropriate  expression "can we say that ..." when "does ..." is a clear, straight  forward question not dependent upon anybody saying anything?   Of course the answer to any "can we say ..." question is always yes, irregardles    
 of any facts, in countries that allow freedom of speach.

Answer (score 2):

No. The irrationals as a subspace of the reals (all in the usual topology) is separable metrisable (so certainly Hausdorff and second countable) but not $\sigma$-compact (e.g. because that would have made the rationals a $G_\delta$ in the reals, which it is not).

Any completely metrisable separable topological vector space like $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ or $\ell^2$ is another such example.

Comment: $\ell^2$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ I thought. So those aren't really different examples

Comment: @Jakobian Sure, but that's not trivial. People are usually seeing them as different, even if they're not *topologically* (only one is normable).